# How to get asynchronous data from one Angular component to another

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying to build a component in Angular 2 that takes an array of data objects, and a filename from a parent component, creates a csv file with the data and downloads the file for the user in the browser using the filename provided.  Basically, a resusable ExportCSV component.
I am having issues finding the proper way to use Observable to accomplish this.  The data needs to be retrieved from a Rest API by the parent component before the child component should operate on it.  The parent component has a separate associated service to retrieve data.  This data is paged on the server and the export should contain the entire result set, not just the current page on the client.  This forces the need to get the whole resultset when the export button is clicked.
If anyone has experience with this, please provide direction on how I should accomplish this.  Thanks in advance!

Here are some snippets of the pertinent code:

```
export class InvoiceListComponent {
invoiceFullList: Observable<Array<Invoice>>;
...
setExportable(event: any) {

    let params = new InvoiceSearchFilter();

    this._invoiceService.getAllInvoices(params)
      .subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        this.invoiceFullList = response.json().data;
      },
      () => { });
   }
}
<csv-export [dataList]="invoiceFullList | async" [fileName]='exportFileName'     (exportClickEvent)="setExportable($event)"></csv-export>

export class CsvExportComponent {
@Input() dataList: Array<any>;
@Input() fileName: string = 'data-export';
@Output() exportClickEvent: EventEmitter<{}> = new EventEmitter();
...
exportIt() {
    this.exportClickEvent.emit();
    if (!this.dataList || this.dataList.length < 1) {
        return false;
    }
    this.buttonEnabled = 'disabled';
    this.convertToCSV(this.dataList);
}
...
}
<button name="export-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-export" [disabled]='buttonEnabled' (click)="exportIt()">CSV Export</button>
```

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed.

Answer (score 1):

One of several methods is to use the `|async` pipe.

parent component's template

```
<child [someInput]="someObservable | async"></child>
```

Comment: I get the following error with that pipe:    Invalid argument '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: `| async` can only be used with `Observable` or `Promise`. `invoiceFullList` is none. What is the actual problem with your code? If you remove ` | async` from the code you posted it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution would be to use `ngIf`, which doesn't render the child component unless there is data in `invoiceFullList`:

```
<csv-export *ngIf="invoiceFullList" [dataList]="invoiceFullList" [fileName]='exportFileName' (exportClickEvent)="setExportable($event)"></csv-export>
```

The `async` pipe is not viable in this case, since `invoiceFullList` is not an Observable. The async pipe is used when you are not manually subscribing, so the async pipe does that for you, but you are subscribing to the request and populating an array, to which async pipe cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for anyone else who may be interested.  I Implemented OnChanges life-cycle hook in my component and the ngOnChanges function to look for changes to my bound data like so:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   if  (changes['dataList'] && this.dataList && this.dataList.length > 0) {
       this.convertToCSV(this.dataList);
   }
}
```